# PHP Static Function Called Twice

Tags: php, error-logging

I'm building a MVC PHP framework. I'm working on error logging. I'm testing a system to show and log (in a .txt file) errors thrown by a try, catch block. Since it's short, I've included the whole of `index.php`:

```php
<?php
  // *** SETUP THE DOCUMENT ***
  // Declare strict_types.
  declare(strict_types = 1);

  // Include the autoload file.
  require_once "classes/autoload.php";

  // Create a new config variable to allow us to call the config file from anywhere.
  new Config();

  // Setup error reporting according to the config.
  error_reporting(Config::$config['defaults']['errReporting']);
  ini_set("display_errors", Config::$config['defaults']['ini_setErrors']);

  // Errors::showCatch("Test");

  try {
    $test = new QueryExamples();
    $test->getTexts();
  } catch (Error $e) {
    Errors::showCatch($e);
  }

  unset($test);
```

I've got an autoloader setup already. I'll include the code of that if anyone wants it. The next bit is a file called `errors.php` which is called by the try, catch and, depending on how the configuration file for the framework is setup, shows the message on the screen and/or sends it to a log file:

```php
class Errors{

    static function showCatch($errMessage){
      // If manual errors are turned on in the config file.
      if(Config::$config['defaults']['manErrors'] == 1){
        // Show the error message.
        echo "<br />{$errMessage}<br />";
      }

      // Log the error.
      Logs::logManError($errMessage);
      die();
    }

}
```

How and where it is logged in the file is handled by another static function in another document:

```php
class Logs{

    static function logManError($errMessage) {
      // If custom error logging is turned on in the config file:
      if (Config::$config['defaults']['customErrorsLogging'] == 1) {
        // Get the file path from the config file.
        $manErrors_file = Config::$config['paths']['customErrors'];

        // Format the error message.
        $logTxt = "New Custom Error - [".date("d/m/Y - H:i:s")."]\n".$errMessage."\n\n";

        file_put_contents($manErrors_file, $logTxt, FILE_APPEND);
      }
    }

}
```

The output in the log file:

```
New Custom Error - [23/03/2020 - 01:50:17]
Error: (Error message)

New Custom Error - [23/03/2020 - 01:50:17]
Error: (Error message)
```

I changed the error message to try and find where the errors were being called:

```php
// Format the error message.
// $logTxt = "New Custom Error - [".date("d/m/Y - H:i:s")."]\n".$errMessage."\n\n";
$logTxt = debug_backtrace()["0"]['file']." ".debug_backtrace()['0']['line']."\n".debug_backtrace()['1']['file']." ".debug_backtrace()['1']['line']."\n\n";
```

The output in the log file:

```
F:\xampp\htdocs\FRED 0.0.0\classes\errors.php 21
F:\xampp\htdocs\FRED 0.0.0\index.php 22

F:\xampp\htdocs\FRED 0.0.0\classes\errors.php 21
F:\xampp\htdocs\FRED 0.0.0\index.php 22
```

`errors.php:21` is where I called the the `Logs:logManError()` static function and `index.php:22` is where I called the `Errors:showCatch()` function in the try, catch block.

I also tried adding a global variable to `index.php` to check how many times the `showCatch()` function was being called:

(index.php)

```php
$GLOBALS['i'] = 0;
```

(errors.php)

```php
$GLOBALS['i'] += 1;

// Log the error.
Logs::logManError($errMessage."<br />".$GLOBALS['i']);
die();
```

The output:

```
New Custom Error - [23/03/2020 - 01:50:17]
Error: (Error message)
1

New Custom Error - [23/03/2020 - 01:50:17]
Error: (Error message)
1
```

Comment: Can you include the surrounding source of your try/catch block? Possibly the try/catch block is being executed twice? In other words, where in your source is this try/catch block? Some context on that part would be needed to further debug since the source you did show appears correct.

Comment: I tried changing how I called the showCatch function. You can see the line commented out. It still produces the same result when I comment out the try catch block and uncomment the Errors::showCatch("Test"); line. The error in the tryCatch block is that the getTexts() method doesn't exist.

Comment: Are you using a debugger? If so, you can set a breakpoint where the log is written, and see the stack trace. If the breakpoint gets hit twice, you'll see where the second one comes from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. Here is the answer. After doing more research there appears to be nothing wrong with my code. It seems that it's something to do with the rewrite engine combined with a few other things. I've included a link to the page that gave me the solution.

https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/duplicate-entries-with-file-put-contents-when-rewriteengine-on/16188/11